# Scrapy gets garbage when scraping .robots.txt

Tags: python, scrapy, robots.txt

I am scraping a site with `scrapy 2.0.1` using `SitemapSpider`, `sitemap_urls = ['<site_root>/robots.txt']` file and in `response.text` field I get some garbage. On other sites same code returns ok (readable `response.text`), but this one site returnsgarbage. If I open that problem site with browser - `robots.txt` opens ok and perfectly readable.

I rotate user-agents from the list of well-known user-agents and 'scrapy-rotating-proxies' package , which seems working fine.

Anybody had similar expereince?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide sufficient information so that others can reproduce the problem on their side

Comment: Not sure I can do that whithout disclosing target site. On other sites the code works as expected.